# Azure storage table permission

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I do not recall having to set permission onto my storage table to access it from a browser (REST over HTTP) directly.

I simply try to ask for http://xxx.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1/Tables

but get an error which looks like

`ResourceNotFound`
The specified resource does not exist.

And there is of course tables in the store.

So my question is, do I have to apply some extra permissions to the table before I can do the above ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to supply an Authorization header for the request as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179405.aspx

Or use a shared access signature, as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee395415.aspx

I believe that only Azure blobs or blob containers can be given unauthenticated public access.